# Completely transfer Google Chrome to another PC

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I know that this was asked before but all the solutions provided do not give the complete result

What we can do:

1. Copy profile (on windows) C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
2. Copy registry key [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\PreferenceMACs]
3. Move passwords by exporting / importing them at chrome://settings/passwords (import feature may require enabling at chrome://flags/#password-import-export (or just search for "import"))

Still after all that steps:

1. My authentication for some web sites gets reset and I have to relogin (not for all of them though)
2. I have to login to Chrome account in the browser to enable sync again

I wonder if it is possible to completely transfer the state of the browser, so I can just start using it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Google Chrome has some encryption on their data with machine key, only coping is not work.
You can try this application https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9PP4M2NK8PC8
They promise to transfer all as https://youtu.be/AWtpvXB5HsU

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).